# Recommendation for a new laptop to use in development day to day life

Tags: laptop, development

I'm a full-time web developer working mostly with Microsoft stack and sometimes various other applications. I wanted to purchase a new laptop, and there is confusion between different laptops I have reviewed online.

Here is my requirement

- I wanted to have a laptop which can run applications for .NET development (VS 2017, SQL Server, etc.)
- My spouse wanted a Linux OS for ROR(ruby and rails) development.
- The machine should be portable, so we can carry it along with us every day.
- It should handle the heavy load (programming, not gaming)
- Decent battery life

Required configuration

- 16 GB RAM
- i5 9Gen
- 250-512GB SSD
- C Type ports
- Thunderbolt 3 port (nice to have)

I have searched accordingly our requirements, and found few options though, a signal option doesn't fit in our requirement or budget. We've limited budget of USD $2000 + $200.

Here are the options

1. Macbook Pro:

Macbook is the middle option, we both can use for our development, however, previous version of .NET(.net framework) wouldn't be supported. Hence, need to installed other software in order to run those applications, or it might happen that some applications wouldn't supported at all. Running VMs for development is a not good option either.

2. Buy two laptops separately

Another option is to buy one windows laptop and one Linux laptop. And here are the option for Windows laptops

Dell XPS 13 - Over budget 
Asus ZenBook - Over budget and mixed review 
Razer Blade 15 - No support where I live

Is there any good suggestion?

Comment: **where** do you live? Give us a country, it will be easier to search.

Comment: I live in India @JanDorniak But I can buy items from US if having international warranty

Comment: If *I* were buying a new laptop, I'd be holding out for an IceLake CPU; big increase in IPC, and AVX512 is really cool (at least for me; I do low-level performance tuning / assembly / microbenchmarks, and also some video encoding where AVX512 has real-world use).  Also Ice Lake graphics performance apparently improved a lot.  Zen2 is interesting, though, and isn't vulnerable to most of the Meltdown / MDS style vulnerabilities that Intel CPUs are, only Spectre.